# PHP header function modifying query string if it is an url

Tags: php, redirect

It is very strange to see that php header function modifying query string if it is an URL. I used header function like this
`header('Location: http://www.example.com/account-type?goto=http://www.google.com/hello');`
This is redirecting to `http://www.example.com/account-type?goto=http/hello` modified query string

And if I use relative URL

`header('Location: /account-type?goto=http://www.google.com/hello');`
this will redirect to `http://www.example.com/account-type?goto=http://www.google.com/hello`

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: You probably need to call [urlencode](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on your goto param.

Comment: [What every web developer must know about URL encoding](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding)

Comment: I hope you're validating your redirection. If not look at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A10-Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards

Comment: The `Location` header *requires* an absolute URI (even if most browsers will quietly recover from your error).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's just a problem of encoding. Try this:

```
$url = urlencode('http://www.google.com/hello');
header('Location: http://www.example.com/account-type?goto=' . $url);
```

Comment: I am facing the problem only with one server. Others are completely ok. same PHP, Apache version.

Comment: Well, I don't know about other the other servers but you definitely need url encoding on this one.